# how to align different element in same horizontal level using CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a demo WEB page which have three panel & each have their own title. I want to align all in horizontally. In other words we have title "Amazon cloud Infrastructure", "Amazon cloud Application" and "Essential healthcare powered by ". I want all these should come in all same horizontal line.

I tried to calculate the `top` of panel 3 title and set the `TOP` to first and second panel but it doesn't work.

this JavaScript doesn't work. can we do the same thing using CSS?

```
let topValue = document.querySelector('#rc20p3 .rh02-ttl').getBoundingClientRect().top
    console.log(topValue);
    document.querySelector('#rc20p2 .rh02w3').style.top = topValue+"px"
    document.querySelector('#rc20p1 .rh02w3').style.top = topValue+"px"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `display:flex` in css at parent div of those child panels. You do not need javascript.

`display:flex` puts all the child element in horizontal line, now to align the children's top use `align-items:flex-start`.

```
<div style="display:flex;align-items:flex-start;">
  <div class="children">child 1</div>
  <div class="children">child 2</div>
  <div class="children">child 3</div>
<div>
```

Comment: can you please check

Answer (score 0):

You should look into flexbox. Look at my example bellow.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent * {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h2>Stack</h2>
  <h3>Overflow</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try on my plunkar

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to inspect plunker code, for smaller screen panels are coming in different rows but for large screen they are being displayed in single row only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1cxH.png)

So for smaller screen **display: flex** is being used but **flex-direction: column** using media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 974px)
.rc20v1 #rc20panels {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

if you want them to be displayed in one single row, change direction to row or use important to override css property:

```
.rc20v1 #rc20panels {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row !important;
}
```

But, now problem is somehow width for panels is 0. so u can define each panel width let suppose 33.33%:

```
.rc20v1 #rc20panels .rc20panel {
    width: 33.33%
}
```

**Please read about flexbox if you haven't yet. Its a powerful tool in css.**